# TFS 2013 Update 2 installed in hive 14 instead of hive15

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, tfs, health-analyzer

We've been testing TFS for SharePoint 2013 on our staging server. After the install health analyzer started giving missing server side dependency errors.

TFS features were installed in the '14' hive instead of the '15' hive.

Example error:

> [MissingSetupFile] File [Features\TfsDashboardBaseUI\default.aspx] is
>   referenced [3] times in the database [contentDB], but exists
>   only under Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 setup folder. Consider
>   upgrading the feature/solution which contains this file to the latest
>   version. One or more setup files are referenced in the database
>   [contentDB], but are not installed on the current farm.
>   Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.

Has anyone had any success in resolving this issue? Also there is an update 4 released in 11/6/14.

Related article:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d507dfe6-db6b-4ecf-a3cd-87154eec38dd/team-foundation-server-20132-sharepoint-2013-sp1-missing-server-side-dependencies?forum=tfsadmin

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a known issue from the related article you posted.

If you don't want to ignore the errors, you could simply remove the erroneous references in the database by using a PowerShell script.

example, http://www.danielroot.info/2014/05/two-sharepoint-scripts-for-those.html